# How to pass data between express routes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I'm making an API call in a `POST` route but for some reason, I can't pass the `JSON` data through `res.render` in the `POST` route. So I'm thinking about passing the JSON object to `GET` route so I can `render` it to the right client page.

Heres my `GET` and `POST` routes:

```
router.get('/bookDetails', (req, res) => {
     res.render('bookDetails');
});

router.post('/bookDetails', (req, res) => {
     let ID = req.body.ID;
     request('https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/' + ID, (err, response, body) => {
     if(!err && response.statusCode == 200){
       let bookdata = JSON.parse(body);
       res.render('bookDetails', {bookdata: bookdata});
    }else{
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
});
```

I can't read the bookdata in my bookDetails.ejs file? Is there another way pass this data to the page?

Comment: Could you do a console.log(body) to see what are you getting from the request call? Normally payload should be the response.

Comment: @VitoMadio I'm getting back the JSON object I want but I try to render in my ejs file it says its undefined.

Comment: Well, If you are receiving a json object you don't neet to parse it, so try: let bookdata = body; instead hope it helps.

Comment: @RockySingh Can you show us how you are accessing `bookdata` in `ejs` file?

Comment: @SridharI resolved the issue. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 1):

On semantic, it should be a GET router to display something about the ID resource.

```
router.get('/bookDetails/:id', (req, res) => {
   let resource = await fetchResourceById
   res.render('bookDetails', resource);
});
```

also, you can define a middleware function to reuse the fetchResource logic, as following:

```
function fetchResourceMiddleware(){
  return function(req, res, next){
    var id = req.query.id || req.body.id
    if(id){
      req.resource = await fetchResource(id)
    }
    next()
  }
}
```

reuse the middleware function for GET and POST router:

```
function renderResource(req, res){
  res.render('bookDetails', req.resource);
}

router.get('/bookDetails/:id', fetchResourceMiddleware(), renderResource)
router.post('/bookDetails', fetchResourceMiddleware(), renderResource)
```

hope helpful, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

After post, your get method will run.
In the get method, you are not sending any data to ejs template, so it will not detect it.
You should redirect in post method, it is bad idea sometimes,